# Android-Record streaming video

Tags: android

I want to record streaming videos ( not video from camera ) so anyone has code to do this task can you share this with me.
Thanks and this is my code to stream videos:

```
public static void play() {

 mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
 Uri video = Uri.parse(path_uri);
 mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);


 mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
 mVideoView.start();

 mVideoView.requestFocus();
 mDialog.dismiss();
 Sipdroid.setIPTVflag(IPTV_PLAYER_STARTED)
```